# Technologies required to develop something like bitlocker

Tags: bitlocker

My idea is to build a full volume encryption as a project. 
I know C# and web technologies like HTML CSS JS and angular. 
I want to build something like
BitLocker and https://www.diskcryptor.org/ , Can anyone guide what should be my first step, I have searched a lot on the web did not found any good starting point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can not do that in C# such sort of tools require kernel drivers which are usually written in C or C++

What you could do though would be to use the dcapi.dll from diskcryptor.org and implement only an own modern looking C# based GUI frontent.
This way you have full control over how the application looks and feals to the user yet don't have to mess around with drivers and boot-loaders.

IMHO that is a decent compromise.

Comment: You shouldn't have answered this in the first place (it's opinion-based and software recs, both of which are grounds for closure), but your answer is blatantly wrong. You can [write C/C++ and access it from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices), meaning C# being used isn't a restriction.